# Convert colum type in PostGiS via DB Manager/ SQL in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql

I have a csv file that I want to bring into a PostGIS database through DB Manager in QGIS. I have a column/ field called "Location" that contains geometry (e.g. (40.789423 -75.628493 232.95452117919922 5). The first two are lon/lat, the second is altitude and third is error for the GPS unit it was collected with. I ONLY need the first two pieces of data (i.e. lon/lat).

When I pull this data into PostGIS database with DB Manager, it will not recognize this column as geometry, but identifies it as TEXT (varchar). I would like to change this, but am having trouble. I prefer to use a GUI, but it will not convert. I am trying to figure out the correct SQL code to do this. Here's my most recent attempt:

ALTER TABLE "schema"."table" ALTER "Location" TYPE geometry USING ("Location"::geometry)

However, this returns the following error message:

parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "40.789423 " <-- parse error at position 10 within geometry

I believe that this is because there is an extra space after the "40.78923". Does this seem correct? If so, how do I fix this?

Comment: Update. My original data appears to be in POINTZM format (lon, lat, altitude, measure). I tried the following:

ALTER TABLE "schema"."table" 
ALTER "Location" TYPE geometry(POINT) 
USING ST_GeomFromText ('POINTZM("Location")')

Comment: did you ever get one of these solutions to work?

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
ALTER TABLE "schema"."table" 
ALTER "Location" TYPE geometry(Point) 
USING ST_Force2D(ST_GeomFromText('POINTZM(' || "Location" || ')'))
```

`ST_Force2D` is optional but is used to only keep the lon.lat values.

Comment: Thanks for your time, thibautg. I get the following error. 

operator is not unique: unknown || geometry
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Update. My original data appears to be in POINTZM format (lon, lat, altitude, measure). I tried the following:

ALTER TABLE "schema"."table" 
ALTER "Location" TYPE geometry(POINT) 
USING ST_GeomFromText ('POINTZM("Location")')

I got this error:

parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "POINTZM("L" <-- parse error at position 10 within geometry

Any thoughts @thibautg?

Comment: I've updated my answer to first create a POINTZM and then convert it to 2D.

Comment: You need the double pipe || to concatenate in PostgreSQL. Do not forget to enclose your text in single quotes and your column names in double quotes.

Comment: Other question: does your "Location" column contains the parenthesis ()? If yes then you must omit them in the concatenation. You should then write ALTER TABLE "schema"."table" 
ALTER "Location" TYPE geometry(Point) 
USING ST_Force2D(ST_GeomFromText('POINTZM' || "Location"))

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. One final question. If I do not want the "Force 2D" but want to keep as POINTZW, do I just remove "ST_Force2D and the associated open and close parentheses? I tried this, 
ALTER TABLE "schema"."table" 
ALTER "Location" TYPE geometry(Point) 
USING ST_GeomFromText('POINTZM(' || "Location" || ')')

Comment: Yes but then you must also change the type of your column to geometry(PointZM) instead of geometry(Point). You should also set the srid to 4326 (WGS84) by using the type geometry(PointZM, 4326)

Answer (score 0):

If you open your CSV up as  'space delimited' in for example LibreOffice Calc, the data is separated nicely...

I took your example string and put it in notepad with headers for each of the 4 data points:

[image]

Then I opened it up in LibreOffice Calc and specified 'space delimited':

[image]

And it looks fine:

[image]

So from there, I would export it out again as a 'comma delimited' CSV, import that new file into PostgreSQL, and follow the steps you're trying to do already...